# Cannot assist with shop upgrade quest on animal crossing: new horizons

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I am not seeing the quest my daughter has for upgrading the shop. I have had to co-op with her resident, drop all the resources I have and then swap leader in order that we can carry on.

I am struggling to see why I cannot see the quest to help with these sort of upgrades.

Am I glitched or is it something to do with my daughter's resident being the first to land... And name the island...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main "advancements" of the game (setting up residents that come as part of Tom Nook requests and not just arriving to open lots, building/upgrading Nook's Cranny, establishing museum, etc.) can only be done by the Resident Representative, who is the first person who moved to the island. Any subsequent villagers to come to the island cannot do these.

You can refer to this guide for a full list of things non-representatives cannot do:
https://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-horizons/Island_Sharing_Guide

Comment: It is getting annoying! Thanks for the information, it appears you cannot transfer the representative powers.